# Change template if tag selected

Tags: theme-development

I've got the following code, which changes the page template if 'street-style' is picked from the categories.

However, I'd like to change this to the tag 'street'. I currently have:

```
function get_custom_cat_template($single_template) {
     global $post;

       if ( in_category( 'street-style' )) {
          $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/street-gallery.php';
     }
     return $single_template;
}

add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_custom_cat_template' ) ;
```

If I change `in_category` to `is_tag`, nothing happens. Is this not possible, or am I doing it incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the function you are looking for is [`has_tag()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_tag) or even more generically [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term).

Your function would then become:

```
function get_custom_cat_template($single_template) {
     global $post;

       if ( has_tag( 'street' )) {
          $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/street-gallery.php';
     }
     return $single_template;
}

add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_custom_cat_template' ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `is_tag()` is used to determine if a tag archive page is displayed, not if a post has a specific tag.

What you are looking for is the function `has_term( $term, $taxonomy, $post )`.

You can use this function for any taxonomy, even the custom ones. Your code would look like this:

```
function get_custom_cat_template($single_template) {
    global $post;

    if ( has_term( 'street-style', 'post_tag', $post ) ) { // please also check just "tag" if post_tag does not work.
        $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/street-gallery.php';
    }
    return $single_template;
}

add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_custom_cat_template' ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference with the alternative answer, which is just `has_tag`?

Comment: `has_tag()` is for Tags only, while `has_term()` works with every taxonomy.